# Unison not ignoring paths

Tags: sync, unison

I'm trying to ignore `.git`, `.bundle` and `node_module` directories from my sync. I've tried a heap of different combinations trying to get it to work but every time I sync I can see all of those directories syncing over to the remote machine.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

`~/.unison/default.prf`

```
# Roots of the synchronization
root = /Users/bob/synced
root = ssh://bob@remotebox/synced

# Paths to synchronize
path = hack/testdir

# Some regexps specifying names and paths to ignore
ignore = Name *.log
ignore = Name .DStore
ignore = Name .DS_Store
ignore = Name *.output
ignore = Name *:*
ignore = Path {*/.git/*}
ignore = Path {*/.bundle/*}
ignore = Path {*/.vagrant/*}
ignore = Path {*/.git}
ignore = Path {*/.bundle}
ignore = Path {*/node_modules}

# Window height
height = 37

# propogate file modification times
times = true

# Log actions to the terminal
log = true

auto = true
batch = true
```

This is syncing from OSX to Windows 10 if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a link to the [Path Specifications and Ignoring Path](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#pathspec) section of the Unison manual because it's my favorite section when answering questions about Unison. Note that `ignore Name = name` ignores any path in which the last component matches `name`. Also

> [The character] `*` matches any sequence of characters not including `/` (and not beginning with `.`, when used at the beginning of a name).

So we can ignore paths just like we ignore certain files types. Accounting for the fact that your `.git`, `.bundle` and `node_module` will all have a leading `/` character, but may be found under a hidden directory that starts with a `.`, the following lines are what you want:

```
ignore = Name {*/,.*/}.git
ignore = Name {*/,.*/}.bundle
ignore = Name {*/,.*/}node_module
```

---

For anyone who just syncs the entire `root` directory, there is an unfortunate corner-case that this doesn't cover: when these files are at the top level, right in the `root` directory you are syncing, in which case there is no leading `/` character. This issue is avoided in the above profile because only the directory `testdir` is being synced with the line `path = hack/testdir`. Anyways, for someone who syncs the whole root directory you could add something like `.*,*` to the globbing patterns, but these patterns will match *any* file with a name like `foo.git` too. So you can either resolve to not have any directories/files named `.git`, etc, in the top level of your `root` directory, or if you're okay matching things like `foo.git` too, then you can use the lines:

```
ignore = Name {.*,*,*/,.*/}.git
ignore = Name {.*,*,*/,.*/}.bundle
ignore = Name {.*,*,*/,.*/}node_module
```

Comment: Thank you so much that has solved all my issues. All my unison issues at least ;)

Comment: @Marklar You're very welcome. Hopefully you can find a StackExchange site to help with each of your other issues as well. :D